# combine specificity and

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, roc, precision-recall, precision

I am performing classification on an imbalanced dataset (70% negatives).
If a prediction is negative I take a specific action otherwise an opposite one. As in both cases some costs are implied, I want to **assess how good the model is at detecting each class**.

To do so, I am calculating TP/(TP+FP) and TN/(TN+FN), along the logloss.

Questions:

1- Is my intuition correct in judging these two metrics the most relevant **for judging how reliable the model**'s predictions are?

2- The costs behind each decision are not constant, but they roughly follow different distributions, one for positives and one for negatives. Let's say two gaussians N(1,2) and N(1.5,3). How can I account for this?

Comment: What do you mean about the costs not being constant? Do you mean that FP incurs a cost of $2$ whole FN incurs a cost of $20$ (to make up some numbers)?

Comment: They depend on a variety of factors, therefore they are not constant. For sake of argument let's say that the cost for FP is a draw from a certain distributions and FN's from another one. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a probability $p_1$ of making one kind of mistake, which incurs a cost that is distributed according to $X_1\sim N(1,2)$, and you have another probability $p_2$ of making a mistake that incurs a cost that is distributed according to $X_2\sim N(1.5,3)$. (How you incur negative cost upon making a mistake is a mystery to me, but I can roll with it.

Then your distribution of costs incurred would be $p_1X_1+p_2X_2$.

However, I do not think your probabilities are sensitivity and specificity, which condition on the outcome that you do not know. (If you knew it, you would not be making mistakes in predicting it.) You might find yourself interested in the probabilities of misclassification given each type of classification (related to PPV and NPV). Better still might be to use the predicted probabilities, particularly if those predictions are calibrated (they might not be) and reflect the true probability of event occurrence.

Comment: side note: the problem has to do with placing orders to a national dispatcher of a certain utility. in broad strokes, sometimes even if you get the position wrong turns out you are making their life easier, so you get rewarded

Comment: My initial idea was actually to draw costs for each output probability and bootstrap estimate the total cost. I think this would give an idea of how robust the model is wrt to the (not well calibrated) probabilities

Comment: how do you define PPC and NPV? aren't they the ones I mention? (I am not good with metric names)

Comment: Perhaps consider posting a new question about the problem you want to solve. Right now, it sounds like you have issues to resolve and have ideas to solve them, so you are asking about those possible solutions instead of asking about the root problem. @shamalaia